# Handling events by stateless functional components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've met two approaches to handle events by stateless functional components:

1)

```
const SomeInputComponent = ({ onTextChange }) => (

  <input type='text' onChange={(e) => onTextChange (e.target.value)} />

);
```

2)

```
const SomeInputComponent = ({ onTextChange }) => {

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    onTextChange(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <input type='text' onChange={handleChange} />
  );
};
```

Which one is more preferable? What are pros and cons?

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that it's mostly about readability, reusability, etc. Personally, I try to use option 2, but if it's really simple component and I'll never reuse the handler sometimes i go for option 1.

However, I'm not happy with it and try to stick with second option. Why? Because often I think I will not reuse the handler or I think it will always be a one-liner, but then I end up rewriting it because I'm reusing it or I'm adding more code to it (often simple `console.log`). That wastes time.

So I'm for consistency. Always use option 2.